# Does elasticsearch recalculate score every time it search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does elasticsearch recalculate the score every time it search? or the more frequent search item will have a higher score than an item never shows up in the search result list?

Answer (score -1):

Score need to be [computed based on your query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html); there is no [relevance feedback mechanism](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/relevance-feedback-on-the-web-1.html) as such.